# Unable to execute any knife commands?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

None of the knife commands is executing I am just getting a time out error... 
Initially I used to have Virtual Box  4.3.38 I did not have any issue at that time after upgrading Virtual Box 5.0.22 I having this issue...
[Same error for all knife commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rlye.png)

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, it can't reach the listed host. Your upgrade probably broke VirtualBox's networking. Fix that.

Comment: Networking is working fine i am able to ping www,google.com